# How to integrate Field collection module in Views?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, views

I have created fields and grouped together with [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. I have attached the group field (containing 4 fields), to user account settings in :  `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`.

Now I am trying to display the content of this field-collection into a view, however I can not do it!

[Views 7.x-3.0-beta3](http://drupal.org/project/views) do not allow me to specify the current user and to get in a table the  field-collection contents. How can I get this contents into a view-kind table?

**UPDATE:** 
I have seen that Field collection module has a patch for Views module here: [Add Views Relationship to Field Collection - patch attached](http://drupal.org/node/1172372) which is already included in [Field collection 7.x-1.x-dev](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/field_collection-7.x-1.x-dev.zip). This allows me to have access at field in collection form Views, however is not allowing me to set a custom filter for the entity of which I associate the field collection. I my case is the user ID.

How can I have access to that form views ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What kind of view are you creating?

Since the collection is being used in the user entity you should create a user view. This will allow you to set the user id filter you want to set.

Once you create that user view you will need to add the field_collection relationship to display those appropriate field.

This is assuming you are using the latest field_collection - dev version.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, your suggestion relay help me in this issue!

Comment: You will get the bonus in 13 hours :) !