# View with field collection and filters

Tags: views

I want to make a profile for musicians. They should type their skills (reference to taxonomy) and levels (radiobuttons) like flute - beginner, piano - advanced,...
Then I need a view with the profile information and the skills and levels. There should be a possibility to search for the skills and levels.
I tried it with a field collection field in the profile but then there is only one exposed filter for the profile field, a textfield for both the skills and levels.
How can I do this? I am getting mad about it. Is there another way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to look at an advanced application of someone doing something very similiar to you, have a look at the [Recruiter installation profile for Drupal 7.](http://epiqo.com/en/recruiter) Just download, install and then look at how the views, content types, taxonomy and fields are configured. Instead of musicians and skill it is configured to software developers with skills.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check this post if anyone is still looking for how to expose properties of a Field Collection. I found it helpful.

[How to integrate Field collection module in Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5101/how-to-integrate-field-collection-module-in-views)